# How to disable Galactic Civilization 3 debug log

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

I am playing Galactic Civilization 3 and I pressed several keys to try to do something. I then got a debug log on the ui, that I can't get rid of. What is the key combination to make it go away?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With default keybindings, `D` will make this graphics debug log appear/disappear.

To change this, from the `options` click on `Input`
[image]

From the `Main` tab, change the `Toggle Debug Text Overlay` to something other than `D`
[image]

Comment: It's actually just "D" (using the default keymapping.)  Once I figured that out, I went into the settings and changed it to a different key far away from anything I might want to press.